# How to automatically detect changes to database and produce a jquery notification?

Tags: php, jquery, notifications

In the website I am maintaining, I wan to add a new feature which functions like the facebook notification.
I want to automatically detect changes in my database, then if a new item was inserted/updated then it will produce a notification.

I found this: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html

It uses Jquery to update a div automatically. I tried it, modified, and it worked :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: _I want to automatically detect changes in my database_ – how did you plan on doing that?

Comment: I dont know if this is possible.
I was thinking of loading a php file every 3 minutes (or less). The php file contains select statement. If there are fetched rows, then the php file will return the fetched rows.
It's like a jquery that automatically refreshes a div, but it should load a php file first, then the jquery will output the results.

Answer (score 3):

For instant notifications you'll need WebSockets, like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) for PHP.

Detecting changes in your database is not easy to implement, easier would be to send a message in PHP when you also update the database.

For this you'll need to create a websocket connection with everyone currently visiting the page. When someone updates or inserts, a message will be sent to all connected users.

Check out this page for a simple tutorial http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: Just an FYI, you probably won't be able to this with most web hosts.

Answer (score 1):

There's a technique called comet (or long-polling) that will help you achieve this. What you **don't** want to be doing is polling the server (via AJAX) every *x* seconds to see if the data has changed- it's wasteful and resource-intensive. Basically what comet does is poll the server to see if there are any new changes to pull, and only when there are actually changes does the server respond. It means that you only hit the server when there is actually new data to be pulled.

It's easy to implement in JavaScript, but since you mention jQuery in your title, there is [this](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Comet) plugin that may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///create-trigger.html) but I would do it a much simpler way:

1- When someone does the needed insert/update, in the same script insert a row in a dedicated table, let's call it `notifications`, for each notification you want to send, it would look something like this:

```
 notifications(id, user_id, message, status)
```

2- Then have a cron job executing every X time that reads said table and sends one notification to the user with said `user_id` and deletes that row from the table (or sets it to "sent" if you want to know what did you sent).

EDIT: crontab example, executing something every 3min.

first type `crontab -e` to edit, then insert the following line:

```
0 */3 * * * complete_path_to_the_script > /dev/null
```

Comment: I got the logic sir..Can you suggest how I can create the cron job thing? That it will select notifications from notifs table every 3 minutes?

Comment: sorry I was out of the office, see the updated answer for the cron job.